# Может ли в e-mail адресе отсутствовать точка?

Tags: email

Адрес e-mail выглядит так: `mailbox@hostname`

Вопрос. Может ли там, где указывается **hostname** полностью отсутствовать точка, после которой указывается домен (например, `.com`)?

То есть, есть ли вероятность, что, например, вот такие e-mail адреса могут существовать и быть полностью валидными: `richard@rewq`, `richard@33`? Здесь после @ идет просто набор букв или цифр и нет точки.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/721927/can-you-have-an-email-address-with-only-the-top-level-domain-as-the-domain-part/721929

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/83723/7485582